# How to prevent browser from refilling form data when navigating back in Django

Tags: django, forms, caching, django-forms

I have a django form that submits data to a database. When the form has been successfully filled out and the data submitted, the form redirects to another page. However, when the user hits the back button on the browser, the data comes back.

Is there a way to prevent the data from coming back?

Comment: As far as I know, this is browser specific, so there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your HTML and it will not cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

If you want a Django specific answer. Try this though the result should be same:

```
response = HttpResponse()  # Created a HttpResponse
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'  # Set Cache-Control Header
```