# Don't refill Django forms with Browser Back Button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-cache

I'm asking a question and the answer could help me a lot. When I'm filling my `Django form`, I press a validate button in order to store data form. Then, I am redirected on a new page (form resume page, home page, ...).

But in my browser, if I click on `Back Button`, my form is already filled with previous data and I can modify data.

**My question is :** How I can prevent browser from refilling form data when navigating back with Django ?

I found this Stackoverflow question : [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851545/how-to-prevent-browser-from-refilling-form-data-when-navigating-back-in-django)

But the answer doesn't seem to work. It's an old answer and I'm supposing it exists an other way to do that ?

**EDIT :**

I used `<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off"> .. </form>` and it seems working with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This is front-end approaching but this would be easy to use if you can use JS and jQuery.

add this code below your HTML Template:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('form').get(0).reset(); //clear form data on page load
});
</script>
```

REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27544317/4741406

Comment: I can use JS and JQuery but it doesn't seem to work. I added this code in my HTML template which display my Django form. I fill the form, I validate it, then when I use Browser back button, my form is still filled.

Comment: if change like this:
`$(window).load(function() {
    $('#form_id').reset(); // declare form id
});`
 still not working?

Comment: `autocomplete` is good but some browser doesn't comply that. beware :)

Comment: I tried with Firefox and Safari, it's ok up to now. I have to try with Chrome, IE ;)

Comment: always IE matters :(  Chrome'll be fine!

Comment: It's not a problem for me, because my Django application will be used with Firefox or Chrome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the back button in your success page after filling the form.
or reset the form : document.getElementById('form').reset();
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20321530/5644965) may help